# Bad conversion of integer into a string using integer'image

Tags: vhdl

I have a problem in my VHDL code. The function integer'image doesn't work properly. In the top of the project I call an entity (region_engine) with two "generate", this is the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;
.....

ENGINE_ROW:
for i in 1 to sqrt_REGIONS_NUMBER generate
begin
    ENGINES_COL:
    for j in 1 to sqrt_REGIONS_NUMBER generate
    begin
        ENGINE_REGION_inst: entity work.region_engine
            PORT MAP         
            ( CLOCK                 => CLOCK,
              RESET                 => RESET,
              HITDATA               => hitdata_region(4*(i-1)+j-1),
              DV                    => data_valid((i-1)*sqrt_REGIONS_NUMBER + j-1),
              BUSY_MAX              => busy_red,
              CLKEN                 => CLKEN_ACC,
              number_i              => (i-1),
              number_j              => (j-1),
              ECS_BUS               => ECS

          );
    end generate ENGINES_COL;
end generate ENGINE_ROW;
```

I pass the index i and j through number_i, number_j defined as integer. Here the code of
region_engine :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity region_engine is
port
(
    CLOCK                   : in    std_logic;
    RESET               : in    std_logic;
    HITDATA                 : in    std_logic_vector(DATA_ENGINE-1 +4 downto 0);
    DV                      : in    std_logic;
    BUSY_MAX                : in    std_logic;
    CLKEN                   : in    std_logic; ---forse non serve
    number_i                : in    integer;
    number_j                : in    integer;
    ECS_BUS             : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)   
);
end entity region_engine;
....

ENGINEs_row :
for k in 0 to 3 generate
begin
ENGINEs_col:
    for m in 0 to 3 generate

     constant romfile_weight : string := "E:\Work\LHCb_Tesi\enginetoy_IT_test_allweight\lut_engine\peso_it\weight_engine_" & integer'image(16*number + k) & ".hex";
     constant romfile_intersect : string := "E:\Work\LHCb_Tesi\enginetoy_IT_test_allweight\lut_engine\intersection_it_256\intersect_engine_" & integer'image(4*number_i + k) & "_" & integer'image((4*number_j + m)) &".hex";

begin

    engine_inst : entity work.engine
    GENERIC MAP
    (
        ENGINE_WEIGHT_FILE      => romfile_weight,
        ENGINE_INTERSECT_FILE   => romfile_intersect
    )
    PORT MAP
    (
        CLOCK               => CLOCK,
        RESET               => RESET,
        HITDATA         => c2(4*k + m)(DATA_ENGINE -1 downto 0),--HITDATA(i)(DATA_ENGINE -1 downto 0),--
        ACC_RESET       => acc_rst,--ed, --EE_delay,
        ACC_EN          => g,--e,--
        ECS_DATA            =>  ECS_BUS(DATA_ENGINE -1 downto 0),
        INTERSECT_ADD   =>  address(4*k +m),
        WRITE_EN            => w_en,--(i),
        ACC_ENG         => acc_16_eng(4*k + m)
    );
    end generate ENGINEs_col;       
end generate ENGINEs_row;
```

I would like to pass to entity engine a file called intersect_engine_x_y.hex. Because of the previously range of indexes, the value 
4*number_i + k and 4*number_j +m
should has a range from 0 to 15. But if I try to simulate the code with modelsim-altera these values don't match with the ones that I expect, in particulary the value 4*number_i - 4*number_j are put to zero.
Instead if I put in the string just number_i, number_j, as follow

```
constant romfile_intersect : string := "E:\Work\LHCb_Tesi\enginetoy_IT_test_allweight\lut_engine\intersection_it_256\intersect_engine_" & integer'image(number_i) & "_" & integer'image((number_j)) &".hex";
```

I read in modelsim this string:

```
"E:\Work\LHCb_Tesi\enginetoy_IT_test_allweight\lut_engine\intersection_it_256\intersect_engine_-2147483648_-2147483648.hex"
```

I don't know the reason for this behaviour, is it possible some trouble with the function integer'image?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The index values i and j should be passed to `region_engine` through generics,
and not ports, so change the entity to:

```
entity region_engine is
  generic (
    NUMBER_I : integer;
    NUMBER_J : integer);
  port (
    CLOCK    : in std_logic;
    RESET    : in std_logic;
    DV       : in std_logic;
    BUSY_MAX : in std_logic;
    CLKEN    : in std_logic;            -- Force non serve
    ECS_BUS  : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end entity region_engine;
```

The generate should be changed accordingly to:

```
ENGINE_ROW :
  for i in 1 to sqrt_REGIONS_NUMBER generate
  begin
    ENGINES_COL :
    for j in 1 to sqrt_REGIONS_NUMBER generate
    begin
      ENGINE_REGION_inst : entity work.region_engine
        generic map (
          NUMBER_I => (i-1),
          NUMBER_J => (j-1))
        port map (
          CLOCK    => CLOCK,
          RESET    => RESET,
          HITDATA  => hitdata_region(4*(i-1)+j-1),
          DV       => data_valid((i-1)*sqrt_REGIONS_NUMBER + j-1),
          BUSY_MAX => busy_red,
          CLKEN    => CLKEN_ACC,
          ECS_BUS  => ECS);
    end generate ENGINES_COL;
  end generate ENGINE_ROW;
```

The reason you see the value -2147483648 used for number_i in the other case,
is that the number_i is uninitialized at the time of use, as a result of the
VHDL execution model, thus having the lowest integer value (`integer'low`),
which is -2**31.  So `integer'image` gives the expected result.

Btw. using both the standard IEEE package `numeric_std` and the non-standard
packages (actually Synopsys proprietary) `std_logic_arith` is very likely to
cause problems since e.g. `unsigned` is declared in both.  So you may consider
removing all the `std_logic_arith`, and only using `numeric_std`.

Comment: Using a port/signal in a constant expression does not seem like it should even compile/elaborate... (really, ModelSim doesn't complain??)

Comment: @fru1tbat: ModelSim in VHDL-2002 mode is OK with a constant expression for the integer input port, like it will also accept `'1' and '0'` for a `std_logic` port, etc.

Comment: It's not the fact that a literal is assigned to an input port that concerns me - in the expression `constant romfile_weight : string := ... number_i ...`, `number_i` is an input port, i.e. not static at all, at least at analysis. I'm very surprised that compiles...

Comment: @fru1tbat:  Good point, and it appears that ModelSim gives a warning like `(vcom-1013) Initial value of "romfile_weight" depends on value of signal "number_i".`